# Check to see if a collection of properties exist inside a dict object in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

What is a good way to check to see if a collection of properties exist inside a dict object in Python?

Currently we are doing this, but it seems like there may be a better way:

```
properties_to_check_for = ['name', 'date', 'birth']
for property in properties_to_check_for:
    if property not in dict_obj or dict_obj[property] is None:
        return False
```

Thanks so much!

Comment: You mean `for property in properties_to_check_for`? Also, don't use `property` as a variable name as it will override the builtin.

Comment: Note that *property* is generally used to mean an attribute on an object (`spam.ham`). Dictionaries have *keys*. Using the terminology correctly makes it easier to work with your code.

Comment: @Lattyware: Good point. That should be one of PEP20 points ;)

Comment: @Volatility - Yes, thats what I meant, I've fixed it. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `all` with a generator:

```
all(key in dict_obj for key in properties_to_check_for)
```

It'll short-circuit, just like your `for` loop. Here's a direct translation of your current code:

```
all(dict_obj.get(key) is not None for key in properties_to_check_for)
```

`d.get(key)` will return `None` if the key isn't in your dictionary, so you don't really need to check if it's in there beforehand.

Comment: +1. `all()` is the less roundabout way to do this, and `dict.get()` is also the best solution. Also, if you don't know about generator expressions, [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pShL9DCSIUw) is a video which explains them, along with list comps and the other cousins.

Answer (score 3):

You could use `any()`:

```
any(dict_obj.get(prop) is None for prop in properties_to_check_for )
```

This will return True if any `property` is not found in `properties_to_check_for` or if it's value is `None`.

Comment: Your solution is exactly opposite to the solution proposed by Blender. Also the result will be the opposite (Blender's gives `True' when all properties are found, `False` otherwise, yours gives exactly opposite). Anyway, upvoting.

Comment: @Tadeck I agree, and even pointed that out. But +1 goes to blender, whose answer is exactly equivalent to OP's code. :)

Answer (score 2):

for large dictionaries versus large list comparisons, comparing the `set`-like object returned by `viewkeys` with a `set` version of `properties_to_check_for` may offer performance benefits

```
if dict_obj.viewkeys() >= set(properties_to_check_for):
```

Timing measurements:

```
timeit.timeit('dict_obj.viewkeys() >= set(properties_to_check_for)', 
setup='dict_obj = dict(zip(xrange(100000), xrange(100000))); properties_to_check_for=xrange(10000)', 
number=10000)
9.82882809638977
timeit.timeit('all(key in dict_obj for key in properties_to_check_for)',
setup='dict_obj =dict(zip(xrange(100000),xrange(100000)));properties_to_check_for=list(xrange(10000))',
number=10000)
12.362821102142334
```

Comment: @Blender, test which part? The expression above or the performance part?

Comment: Note that in 3.x, `dict.keys()` produces a view like `dict.viewkeys()` does in 2.x.